# Could the buffers and textures of different windows share the same binding point in OpenGL while realizing OIT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Firstly I want to say that I have already realized the PPLL(Per-Pixel Linked Lists) to draw transparently, and everything seems to be rather normal. The problem occurred in the time when I try to use PPLL in multiple windows.

I'm using OpenGL 4.5 + QT in my program. The user interface sketch is shown as follows:
[image]

The interface divides into two parts, window 0 and 1, and they are rendering same things from different angles. A window 2 will be opened and closed occasionally to show other things.

All the three windows can be rendered in transparent mode normally. However, when a window 2 is closed, window 0 will turn to be flickering and colorless (while window 2 is still normal), as the following picture shows.

[image]

The following are some realization details of the PPLL in each window.

The three windows use the same shader. It's worth noting that the images in fragment shaders for PPLL share the same binding points for each window.

```
layout (binding = 0, r32ui)         uniform uimage2D head_pointer_image;        // save the head pointers for all pixels
layout (binding = 1, rgba32ui)      uniform writeonly uimageBuffer list_buffer; // save every fragment data
layout (binding = 0, offset = 0)    uniform atomic_uint list_counter;           // used to assign a unique index for each fragment
```

Each window has its own resources (buffers and textures) for PPLL, and the resources will be applyed when the window is initialized and deleted when the window is closed.

```
GLuint m_headPointerTexture;
GLuint m_headPointerClearBuffer;
GLuint m_atomicCounterBuffer;
GLuint m_linkedListBuffer;
GLuint m_linkedListTexture;
....
glDeleteTextures(1, &m_headPointerTexture);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_headPointerClearBuffer);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_atomicCounterBuffer);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &m_linkedListBuffer);
glDeleteTextures(1, &m_linkedListTexture);
```

I have two conjectures for the error render of window 0:

1. Different windows should use different binding points for the images defined in glsl.
2. Different windows should share the resources (buffers and textures).

I have run kinds of tests for each conjecture, but the results are all unsatisfactory.

UPDATE:

It's a complex project. I'm not entirely sure the error is related to the PPLL. When object A and B are both drawn on window 0 and 1, the error will occur. However, when I only draw object A (or B) on window 0 and 1, the error will not occur. It's rather strange. I'm completely out of my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs in the time when a window 2 is closed, so it's related to the release of the resources applied by window 2.

Adjusting the order of the deconstruction of window 2 properly will solve the problem.